# python.exe started to require full file path while using open() for a file in same folder

Tags: python, path, pycharm, anaconda

I was opening a file which is in the same folder with .py file without full path.

```py
file=open("eggs.txt", "r")
```

When I run the .py file it was running in Python command screen, properly.

Untill I install PyCharm and Anaconda. After that installations I can not run .py file with neither from default Python.exe nor Python.exe from Anaconda directory

```
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\python.exe
C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python.exe
```

Both produce the error below:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'foo.txt'
```

If I write full path of the file or I run the script from PyCharm's shell it is working.

What is causing this change? Is this due to Anaconda? How can I fix it?

PS: I don't want to use any solutions that retrieve current folder path somehow. I need to understand what is changed.

Comment: You are no longer calling Python from the directory that contains the file, Python is running from whichever directory your `python.exe` file lives in.

Comment: If you use `open('foo.txt')`, then that file must be in the _current working directory_.  It does not matter where the python executable is located.

Comment: Are you running python from the command line, or from a desktop shortcut/icon?  If the latter, does the shortcut impose a specific working directory?  (For Windows, this is the "Start In" field when inspecting the shortcut properties.)

Comment: @MasonCaiby my python.exe is living in ```C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python.exe``` still. It is not changed.

Comment: @JohnGordon .txt file is in same directory with my .py file. Isn't it the _current working directory_ ?

Comment: @JohnGordon I am running python from "open with" option of windows.

Comment: Perhaps the "open with" context menu option is using the Python executable location as the working directory?  You can test this by making a small python script that just prints `os.getcwd()`

Comment: @JohnGordon Your above comment is what I assumed, sorry for the implicit statement. It sounds like Python is running from its executable's location, making the cwd `C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\`.

Comment: I tested. It seems cwd for "open with" option is ```C:\WINDOWS\System32``` and previously I was opening the .py file directly by doubleclick. By that way the cwd became the same folder with the .py file. Thank you @JohnGordon